Docker build not detecting ENV variables from Dockerfile
I have a Dockerfile that looks like this:
FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.16

# install dependencies
RUN apk --no-cache add curl bash
RUN mkdir /nextflow; \
    chmod 777 /nextflow; \
    cd /nextflow; \
    curl -s https://get.nextflow.io | bash; \
    chmod a+x /nextflow/nextflow;
RUN ln -s /nextflow/nextflow /usr/local/bin/nextflow; \
    chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/nextflow;

# install kubectl
RUN cd /usr/local/bin; curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"; chmod a+x kubectl

WORKDIR /nextflow

# SCM file might need to be overwritten
ADD scm /nextflow/scm_template
ENV NXF_SCM_FILE=/nextflow/scm

# Add stats gathering cron
ADD gather_stats.sh /nextflow/gather_stats.sh
ADD gather_stats_runner.sh /nextflow/gather_stats_runner.sh

ENV NXF_SCM_USER=''
ENV NXF_SCM_TOKEN=''
ENV NXF_STATS_INTERVAL_SECONDS=60
ENV NXF_STATS_ECHO=1
ENV NXF_STATS_COLLECT=1
ADD entrypoint.sh /nextflow/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/nextflow/entrypoint.sh"]


When I run docker build -t my_app . in a Mac with M1 chip and Docker version 26.0.0, build 2ae903e, only 10/17 steps are ran. All the steps except for the ones where I declare ENV VARIABLE_NAME=some_val are ran.
However, when I run the same command (docker build -t my_app .) in a linux machine with Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243 17/17 steps are ran, including those ones where I declare ENV....
I don't understand why this is happening.
Mac output from docker build:
[+] Building 98.1s (16/16) FINISHED                                                                                                                      docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.05kB                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.16                                                                                          1.4s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.16@sha256:be9d81f2be1232657ec724aa9922f75590249e7c3ef7fad820cccac42163213c                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 135B                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [ 2/11] RUN apk --no-cache add curl bash                                                                                                                             3.3s
 => [ 3/11] RUN mkdir /nextflow;     chmod 777 /nextflow;     cd /nextflow;     curl -s https://get.nextflow.io | bash;     chmod a+x /nextflow/nextflow;               32.9s
 => [ 4/11] RUN ln -s /nextflow/nextflow /usr/local/bin/nextflow;     chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/nextflow;                                                                 0.1s 
 => [ 5/11] RUN cd /usr/local/bin; curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"; chmod a+x kubectl   60.1s 
 => [ 6/11] WORKDIR /nextflow                                                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => [ 7/11] ADD scm /nextflow/scm_template                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [ 8/11] RUN echo "/nextflow/scm"                                                                                                                                     0.1s
 => [ 9/11] ADD gather_stats.sh /nextflow/gather_stats.sh                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [10/11] ADD gather_stats_runner.sh /nextflow/gather_stats_runner.sh                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [11/11] ADD entrypoint.sh /nextflow/entrypoint.sh                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                   0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
 => => writing image sha256:020922b02dab652881f799311a15d2e6029502c6393a664e3d1910b4253153aa                                                                             0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/nextflow-launcher                                                                                                                     0.0s

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/8mynmt8xh2ker5f7zobosdata

What's Next?
  View a summary of image vulnerabilities and recommendations → docker scout quickview

Linux output from docker build:
Sending build context to Docker daemon  116.2kB
Step 1/18 : FROM amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.16
 ---> d1cbdc507ae8
Step 2/18 : RUN apk --no-cache add curl bash
 ---> Running in c793d2432751
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.16/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://apk.corretto.aws/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/9) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.3_p20220521-r1)
(2/9) Installing ncurses-libs (6.3_p20220521-r1)
(3/9) Installing readline (8.1.2-r0)
(4/9) Installing bash (5.1.16-r2)
Executing bash-5.1.16-r2.post-install
(5/9) Installing ca-certificates (20240226-r0)
(6/9) Installing brotli-libs (1.0.9-r6)
(7/9) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.47.0-r2)
(8/9) Installing libcurl (8.5.0-r0)
(9/9) Installing curl (8.5.0-r0)
Executing busybox-1.35.0-r17.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20240226-r0.trigger
OK: 322 MiB in 25 packages
Removing intermediate container c793d2432751
 ---> 5fd6d6e69db7
Step 3/18 : RUN mkdir /nextflow;     chmod 777 /nextflow;     cd /nextflow;     curl -s https://get.nextflow.io | bash;     chmod a+x /nextflow/nextflow;
 ---> Running in 5c6b322710b4
tty: ignoring all arguments
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.apache.groovy:groovy:jar:4.0.21
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.multiverse:multiverse-core:jar:0.7.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.14
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.17.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency io.nextflow:nextflow:jar:24.04.3
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.11.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:2.2
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.eclipse.jgit:org.eclipse.jgit:jar:6.6.1.202309021850-r
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.beust:jcommander:jar:1.35
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.apache.ivy:ivy:jar:2.5.2
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency jline:jline:jar:2.9
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:2.0.7
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.github.zafarkhaja:java-semver:jar:0.9.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.google.guava:guava:jar:33.0.0-jre
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4.7
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.23.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.7
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb-api:jar:0.12
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:jar:1.2.1
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:jar:2.24.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.apache.groovy:groovy-templates:jar:4.0.21
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.2
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.10.1
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.googlecode.javaewah:JavaEWAH:jar:1.2.3
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.apache.groovy:groovy-xml:jar:4.0.21
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency dev.failsafe:failsafe:jar:3.1.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.14
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1.1
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.17.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.9
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.7
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.apache.groovy:groovy-yaml:jar:4.0.21
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency io.nextflow:nf-httpfs:jar:24.04.3
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.pf4j:pf4j-update:jar:2.3.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.pf4j:pf4j:jar:3.10.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.apache.groovy:groovy-json:jar:4.0.21
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:jar:1.7.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.15
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.apache.groovy:groovy-nio:jar:4.0.21
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.checkerframework:checker-qual:jar:3.41.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:2.0.7
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.15.4
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.1
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency ch.artecat.grengine:grengine:jar:3.0.2
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.17.0
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency io.nextflow:nf-commons:jar:24.04.3
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency org.iq80.leveldb:leveldb:jar:0.12
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.17.0
21:46:14.573 [main] DEBUG nextflow.cli.Launcher -- Unexpected terminal $COLUMNS value: not a tty

      N E X T F L O W
      version 24.04.3 build 5916
      created 09-07-2024 19:35 UTC (19:35 GMT)
      cite doi:10.1038/nbt.3820
      http://nextflow.io


Nextflow installation completed. Please note:
- the executable file `nextflow` has been created in the folder: /nextflow
- you may complete the installation by moving it to a directory in your $PATH

Removing intermediate container 5c6b322710b4
 ---> c76de7c53fe4
Step 4/18 : RUN ln -s /nextflow/nextflow /usr/local/bin/nextflow;     chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/nextflow;
 ---> Running in 24c392c4636e
Removing intermediate container 24c392c4636e
 ---> 7ed336faeaaa
Step 5/18 : RUN cd /usr/local/bin; curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"; chmod a+x kubectl
 ---> Running in 4b148d9eb835
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   138  100   138    0     0    907      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   907
100 49.0M  100 49.0M    0     0  68.1M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  108M
Removing intermediate container 4b148d9eb835
 ---> 8f6a24bf62eb
Step 6/18 : WORKDIR /nextflow
 ---> Running in 8e3ee0694213
Removing intermediate container 8e3ee0694213
 ---> 0fde23a23a45
Step 7/18 : ADD scm /nextflow/scm_template
 ---> b37a20c3d1da
Step 8/18 : ENV NXF_SCM_FILE=/nextflow/scm
 ---> Running in 2176f26d3695
Removing intermediate container 2176f26d3695
 ---> 05ecf48d7247
Step 9/18 : RUN echo "${NXF_SCM_FILE}"
 ---> Running in eb094786b82d
/nextflow/scm
Removing intermediate container eb094786b82d
 ---> 63c990864f40
Step 10/18 : ADD gather_stats.sh /nextflow/gather_stats.sh
 ---> 94e3192764ee
Step 11/18 : ADD gather_stats_runner.sh /nextflow/gather_stats_runner.sh
 ---> da1feb82ab52
Step 12/18 : ENV NXF_SCM_USER=''
 ---> Running in 4d7d15a6a926
Removing intermediate container 4d7d15a6a926
 ---> 8e70509ecced
Step 13/18 : ENV NXF_SCM_TOKEN=''
 ---> Running in 743b4e1a3b80
Removing intermediate container 743b4e1a3b80
 ---> 92c623414100
Step 14/18 : ENV NXF_STATS_INTERVAL_SECONDS=60
 ---> Running in 51967552264c
Removing intermediate container 51967552264c
 ---> 5d886443d07e
Step 15/18 : ENV NXF_STATS_ECHO=1
 ---> Running in 3a5bdde6f23c
Removing intermediate container 3a5bdde6f23c
 ---> 1f8f316b7923
Step 16/18 : ENV NXF_STATS_COLLECT=1
 ---> Running in 6dfb333f0c21
Removing intermediate container 6dfb333f0c21
 ---> f516ef2f2652
Step 17/18 : ADD entrypoint.sh /nextflow/entrypoint.sh
 ---> b40ed6df6738
Step 18/18 : ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/nextflow/entrypoint.sh"]
 ---> Running in 5cbf00087db6
Removing intermediate container 5cbf00087db6
 ---> aedde75e8d64
Successfully built aedde75e8d64
Successfully tagged my_app:latest


Importantly, is the omission from the output because the ENV step is not being effected? You can test this by outputting the value of one/more of the variables after you've set it e.g. RUN echo "${NXF_SCXM_FILE}"

@DazWilkin I tried running RUN echo "${NXF_SCXM_FILE}" as you suggested but I see no output.

Interesting. Please update your question with the docker build output from the Linux and Mac machines

@DazWilkin question updated with outputs from both machines.

That is curious. I don't know. I wondered whether it was eliding the ENV statements on the Mac (for some reason) but it does indeed seem to be skipping them (numbering) and demonstrated by the absence of values once set (RUN echo ...)

@DazWilkin sorry, deleted the RUN echo from the file because I thought the output from the original Dockerfile was needed. Just updated the logs from both machines which include the print of the variable. Also, I was referencing the wrong variable at the beginning but now I can see the correct value during the print/echo.
